# Problema ao serializar um objeto

Tags: c#, serialização

Estou tentando utilizar serialização para transferir dados entre Servidor e Cliente. Entretanto, estou tendo problemas ao tentar desserializar uma classe que tenha uma Lista de tipo de uma outra classe, quando a classe a ser desserializada não possui uma lista desse tipo não ocorre nenhum erro.

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função para serializar:

```
private static void Serialize(NetOutgoingMessage Data, object Element)
{
    // Serializa os dados
    MemoryStream Stream = new MemoryStream();
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(Stream, Element);
    Data.Write(Stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    Data.Write(Stream.GetBuffer());
    Stream.Close();
}
```

Função para deserializar:

```
private static object Deserialize(NetIncomingMessage Data)
{
    // Deserializa os dados
    BinaryFormatter Formater = new BinaryFormatter();
    Formater.Binder = new Program.Binder();
    return Formater.Deserialize(new MemoryStream(Data.ReadBytes(Data.ReadInt32())));
}
```

Binder:

```
public class Binder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace("Client", "Server");
        return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}", typeName, assemblyName));
    }
}
```

Classes a ser serializada:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class NPC
    {
        public string Name;
        public string SayMsg;
        public short Texture;
        public byte Behaviour;
        public byte SpawnTime;
        public byte Sight;
        public int Experience;
        public short[] Vital;
        public short[] Attribute;
        public List<NPC_Drop> Drop;
        public bool AttackNPC;
        public List<short> Allie;
        public byte Movement;
        public byte Flee_Helth;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class NPC_Drop
    {
        public short Item_Num;
        public short Amount;
        public byte Chance;
    }
```

Como eu envio os dados:

```
public static void Write_NPCs()
{
    NetOutgoingMessage Data = Socket.Device.CreateMessage();

    // Envia os dados
    Data.Write((byte)Packets.Write_NPCs);
    Serialize(Data, Lists.NPC);
    Packet(Data);
}
```

Como eu recebo:

```
private static void Write_NPCs(byte Index, NetIncomingMessage Data)
{
    // Lê e salva os dados 
    Lists.NPC = (Lists.Structures.NPC[])Deserialize(Data);
    Write.NPCs();
}
```

Comment: Código estranho, porque você está fazendo assim, porque não utiliza um cara pra fazer isso para você?

Comment: como assim um cara? @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Já existe pacote que faz isso !!! porque está fazendo assim?

Comment: Complementando o que o Virgilio comentou, vou fazer um jabá gratuito aqui mas geralmente é utilizado o newtonsoft json, inclusive achei no git do .net uma conversa bem construtiva sobre a utilizacao do binaryformatter estar sendo depreciada https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23341#issuecomment-325826116